# htaccess redirect url with or without trailing slash to new url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an old url like http://website.com/post/123/ and some urls like http://website.com/post/123 were indexed instead of the url with the trailing slash. I'm looking for a rewite to 301 redirect either old url (with or without trailing slash) to a new url like http://www.newwebsite.com/123post.html.

So far, I've found a method to redirect the specefic url, but I'm unsure of how to redirect both variations of the old url.

Heres what i have so far...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteRule ^post/123$ http://www.newwebsite.com/123post.html [R=301,L]
```

Will this work for urls with and without trailing slash?

Comment: How about this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/123/?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/123post.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! I see you combined the www/non-www rule as well. That was a nice help. I'll accept this answer as soon as the system allows. Thanks anubhava